# Creating python new dataframe from exiting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in below given format:

```
ID_1 Code_M ID_2  Year     PI_code DI_code Sex No_of_PI No_of_DI Days_1 Days_2
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di100    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di200    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di300    2     1        1      100    100
1    DM     100   2019_03  p106    di400    2     1        1      100    100  
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di100    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di200    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di300    2     1        1      200    200
2    XZ     200   2019_03  p107    di400    2     1        1      200    200
```

I need to convert it into below given format where I get individual columns of distinct PI_code and value of these column have to be summation of values present in column No_of_PI similarly I need individual columns of distinct DI_code and value of these column have to be values present in
No_of_DI column output format is given  below:

```
ID_1 Code_M ID_2  Year     P106  P107 di100 di200 di300 di400 Sex Days_1 Days_2
1     DM    100   2019-03   4     Null    1     1     1     1     2   100   100
1     XZ    200   2019-03   Null   4      1     1     1     1     1   200   200
```

Here value 4 in P106 column is summation of all No_of_PI values corresponding p106 rows present in
PI_code column and value in di100 column is equal to 1 as value in present in No_of_DI for row corresponding to di100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are smarter solutions, but because it's not a simple pivot, the solution can't be so simple either. So I split the soluton into two parts.

```
# Part 1 DI values
# pivot table to get the Di_code columns and values
di_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ,"Days_1","Days_2","Sex","PI_code"],
                        columns=["DI_code"],
                        values=["No_of_DI"])

di_pivot=di_pivot.reset_index()  
# Add new column names
cols=  ["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ,"Days_1","Days_2","Sex","PI_code"]
cols.extend([x for x in di_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1) if x != ''])
di_pivot.columns = cols

# Part 2 PI values
# Summarize PI_code value then pivot
pi_grouped=df.groupby(by=["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year","PI_code"], 
                      as_index=False).agg({"No_of_PI":'sum'})
 
pi_grouped_pivot=pd.pivot_table(pi_grouped,index=["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ],
                                columns=["PI_code"],
                                values=["No_of_PI"])
 
pi_grouped_pivot=pi_grouped_pivot.reset_index()  
 
# Add new column names
cols=  ["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year"]
cols.extend([x for x in pi_grouped_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1) if x != ''])
pi_grouped_pivot.columns = cols
 
# join the two dataframe
final_df = pi_grouped_pivot.merge(di_pivot, on = ["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year"])

# The final output format
final_df = final_df[['ID_1', 'Code_M', 'ID_2', 'Year', 'p106', 'p107', 
   'di100', 'di200', 'di300', 'di400','Sex', 'Days_1', 'Days_2',]]
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your solution second part is working correctly and I'm getting correct row but in first part it' giving nan values and condition I was working was modified and I asked another question for it can you please check and help me need it urgently - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912708/creating-dataframe-in-python-based-on-user-requirement

Comment: I have taken a look of the another post, and I think I understand the problem.
Just remove the PI_code column from the index.

`di_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID_1", "Code_M", "ID_2",  "Year" ,"Days_1","Days_2","Sex"],
                        columns=["DI_code"],
                        values=["No_of_DI"])`

Comment: cols.extend([x for x in di_pivot.columns.get_level_values(1) if x != '']) can you please explain what this piece of code is doing I'm getting 2 rows for di_code pivot having nan values ideally it should be returning single row with no nan values as data has no missing values

Comment: Can you please help on this question all it needs is to remove an aggregation from your code but not sure how it is to be done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083962/how-to-remove-aggregation-done-data-in-python-or-sql